# Bars arround windows while using custom theme ubuntu 15.10

Tags: themes

I just updated my laptop to Ubuntu 15.10 and I'm having a problem while using custom themes.

I've downloaded Ultra Flat theme from [noobslab website](http://www.noobslab.com/2015/08/looking-for-completely-flat-design.html) and in some applications (I've detected the issue under nautilus and system preferences) it's not showing well. There is some bars around the window.

[Bars around the window of system preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taOT3.png)

I've removed all themes to see if there is a conflict between them or something like that, then reboot and installed just Ultra flat theme.

I've used unity tweak tool and ubuntu tweak to apply the themes. What can I do to fix the problem?

I've asked too under Nooblab's website.

Thank you so much.

Comment: In Google+ One transistor(profile: https://plus.google.com/u/1/111610285608865716766/posts) has help me with the issue and it has been "resolved" (with a workaround). In case someone is having this issue too, here is how to solve it:  http://www.webupd8.org/2015/11/fix-large-black-borders-around-header.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See solution on [WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/11/fix-large-black-borders-around-header.html). Here is what it takes. Open a Terminal and:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/gtk-3.0
gedit ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
```

In the text editor window that appears enter:

```
.window-frame {
    box-shadow: none;
    margin: 1px;
}
```

Save file. Log out and then log back in.